# It is possible to only display my software without any gui in the background (like no desktop)

Tags: google-chrome, gui, kiosk

I would like not to show my desktop when starting Ubuntu and only show Chrome browser, so that my computer would use less resources because it wouldn't have to draw the desktop. When my project is finished, the goal is only to show web pages, so I don't really have interest in the desktop, that will only be used by admin for technical changes.

Is there anyway to do that? Is it what you English folks call a "kiosk"?

Comment: Using Chrome and worrying about resources is somehow schizophrenic ...

Comment: Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122717/236063